# Drawing triangles on each piece of a canvas pie graph to make arrows

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Using canvas, I have to take some data that is used to create a pie graph, and turn that pie graph into a circle of arrows.

So far the pie graph is simple, and cutting out the middle is easy. But can't figure out how to

1. get the x, y points of each end point of the pie peices.
2. use that to somehow draw a triangle, and
3. continue onto the next pie piece.

What I do have is the x, y of the center point of the circle, and the radius. 
I can draw 1 triangle -

```js
var friends=alumni=hopefuls=athletes=0, 
    data = ['Ahtlete', 'Athlete', 'Friend', 'Friend', 'Athlete'];
    test = data.length;

for (var i = 0; i < test; i++){
    if ( data[i] == "Athelete" ) {
      athletes++;
    } else if ( data[i] == "Friend"){
      friends++;
    } else if (data[i] == "Hopeful" ){
      hopefuls++;
    } else if (data[i] == "Alumni"){
      alumni++
    }
}

var mychart = new AwesomeChart('segmented-circle');
//friends, alumni, hopefuls, athletes;
mychart.colors = ['#d20007','#02f2fb', '#d2ebf6', '#0554ff']
mychart.title = "";
mychart.data = [friends, alumni, hopefuls, athletes];
mychart.labels = [];
mychart.chartType = 'ring';
mychart.draw();



function AwesomeChart(canvasElementId){
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasElementId);
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.width = this.ctx.canvas.width;
    this.height = this.ctx.canvas.height;
    
    this.numberOfDecimals = 0;
    
    this.proportionalSizes = true;
    this.widthSizeFactor = this.width/400;
    this.heightSizeFactor = this.height/400;
    
    this.chartType = 'bar';
    this.randomColors = false;
    
    this.marginTop = 10;
    this.marginBottom = 10;
    this.marginLeft = 20;
    this.marginRight = 50;
    
    this.labelMargin = 10;
    this.dataValueMargin = 20;
    this.titleMargin = 10;
    this.yAxisLabelMargin = 5;
    
    this.data = new Array();
    this.labels = new Array();
    this.colors = new Array();
    this.title = null;
    
    this.backgroundFillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0)';
    this.borderStrokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0)';
    this.borderWidth = 0;
    
    this.labelFillStyle = 'rgb(220, 36, 0)';
    this.labelFont = 'sans-serif';
    this.labelFontHeight = 12;
    this.labelFontStyle = '';
    
    this.dataValueFillStyle = '#333';
    this.dataValueFont = 'sans-serif';
    this.dataValueFontHeight = 15;
    this.dataValueFontStyle = '';
    
    this.titleFillStyle = '#333';
    this.titleFont = 'sans-serif';
    this.titleFontHeight = 16;
    this.titleFontStyle = 'bold';
    
    this.yAxisLabelFillStyle =  '#333';
    this.yAxisLabelFont = 'sans-serif';
    this.yAxisLabelFontHeight = 10;
    this.yAxisLabelFontStyle = '';
    
    var lingrad = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,this.height);
    lingrad.addColorStop(0.2, '#fdfdfd');
    lingrad.addColorStop(0.8, '#ededed');
    
    this.chartBackgroundFillStyle = lingrad;
    this.chartBorderStrokeStyle = '#999';
    this.chartBorderLineWidth = 1;
    this.chartHorizontalLineStrokeStyle = '#999';
    this.chartHorizontalLineWidth = 1;
    this.chartVerticalLineStrokeStyle = '#999';
    this.chartVerticalLineWidth = 1;
    
    this.chartMarkerSize = 5;
    
    this.chartPointRadius = 4;
    this.chartPointFillStyle = 'rgb(150, 36, 0)';
    
    this.chartLineStrokeStyle = 'rgba(150, 36, 0, 0.5)';
    this.chartLineWidth = 2;
    
    this.barFillStyle = 'rgb(220, 36, 0)';
    this.barStrokeStyle = '#fff';
    this.barBorderWidth = 2.0;
    this.barShadowColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
    this.barShadowBlur = 5;
    this.barShadowOffsetX = 3.0;
    this.barShadowOffsetY = 0.0;
    
    this.barHGap = 20;
    this.barVGap = 20;
    
    this.explosionOffset = 20;

    this.pieFillStyle = 'rgb(220, 36, 0)';
    this.pieStrokeStyle = '#fff';
    this.pieBorderWidth = 2.0;
    this.pieShadowColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)';
    this.pieShadowBlur = 15;
    this.pieShadowOffsetX = 0.0;
    this.pieShadowOffsetY = 0.0;
    
    this.pieStart = 0;
    this.pieTotal = null;
    
    this.generateRandomColor = function(){
        var rgb = new Array();
        for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
            rgb.push(Math.ceil(Math.random()*150 + 50));
        }
        return 'rgb('+rgb.join(",")+')';
    }


    this.draw = function(){
        var context = this.ctx;
        context.lineCap = 'round';
        var minFactor = Math.min(this.widthSizeFactor, this.heightSizeFactor);
        
        if(this.proportionalSizes){            
            this.labelMargin = this.labelMargin * this.heightSizeFactor;
            this.dataValueMargin = this.dataValueMargin * this.heightSizeFactor;
            this.titleMargin = this.titleMargin * this.heightSizeFactor;
            this.yAxisLabelMargin = this.yAxisLabelMargin * this.heightSizeFactor;
            
            this.labelFontHeight = this.labelFontHeight * minFactor;
            this.dataValueFontHeight = this.dataValueFontHeight * minFactor;
            this.titleFontHeight = this.titleFontHeight * minFactor;
            this.yAxisLabelFontHeight = this.yAxisLabelFontHeight * minFactor;
            
            this.barHGap = this.barHGap * this.widthSizeFactor;
            this.barVGap = this.barHGap * this.heightSizeFactor;
            this.explosionOffset = this.explosionOffset * minFactor;
        }
        
        if(this.randomColors){
            for(var i=0; i<this.data.length; i++){
                if(!this.colors[i]){
                    this.colors[i] = this.generateRandomColor();
                }
            }
        }

       this.drawPieChart(true);
        
        
        
        //Draw the outer border:
        
        context.lineWidth = this.borderWidth;
        context.strokeStyle = this.borderStrokeStyle;
        context.strokeRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
        
        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
            
        //Fill the background:
        
        context.fillStyle = this.backgroundFillStyle;
        context.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
            
        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
        
    }
  
    this.drawPieChart = function(ring){
        var context = this.ctx;
        context.lineWidth = this.pieBorderWidth;
        var dataSum = 0;
        if(this.pieTotal == null){
            var len = this.data.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                dataSum += this.data[i];
                if(this.data[i]<0){
                    return;
                }
            }
        }else{
            dataSum = this.pieTotal;
        }

        var pieAreaWidth = this.width - this.marginLeft - this.marginRight;
        var pieAreaHeight = this.height - this.marginTop - this.marginBottom;
        
        var centerX = this.width / 2;
        var centerY = this.marginTop + (pieAreaHeight / 2);
        var doublePI = 2 * Math.PI;
        var radius = (Math.min( pieAreaWidth, pieAreaHeight) / 2);

        var maxLabelWidth = 0;
        var labelWidth = 0;
        
        context.font = this.labelFontStyle + ' ' + this.labelFontHeight + 'px '+ this.labelFont;
        
        for (var i = 0; i < this.labels.length; i++){
            labelWidth = context.measureText(this.labels[i]).width;
            if(labelWidth > maxLabelWidth){
                maxLabelWidth = labelWidth;
            }
        }
        
        radius = radius - maxLabelWidth - this.labelMargin;
        
        var startAngle = this.pieStart * doublePI / dataSum;
        var currentAngle = startAngle;
        var endAngle = 0;
        var incAngleBy = 0;
        
        for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++){
            context.beginPath();
            incAngleBy = this.data[i] * doublePI / dataSum;
            endAngle = currentAngle + incAngleBy;


            // Draw pie graph then using same calculations 
            // draw an isoceles triangle at end points before the center
            // is cut out to make the arrows
            context.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
            context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, currentAngle, endAngle, false);
            context.lineTo(centerX, centerY);
            
            var twidth = 15;  // Triangle Width
            var theight = 20; // Triangle Height
            context.moveTo(centerX+radius/2, centerY+radius/2);
            context.lineTo(centerX+radius, centerY+radius);
            context.lineTo(centerX+radius-10, centerY+radius/3);
            context.lineTo(centerX, centerY);
/*
            var width = 15;  // Triangle Width
            var height = 20; // Triangle Height
            var padding = endAngle;

            context.save();
            context.moveTo(centerX, dataSum);
            context.arc(centerX *2, dataSum, 5, 0, doublePI, false);
            context.moveTo(padding + width / 2, padding);        // Top Corner
            context.lineTo(padding + width, height + padding);     // Bottom Right
            context.lineTo(centerX , height + padding);         // Bottom Left
*/

            

            currentAngle = endAngle;
            
            if (this.colors[i]){
                context.fillStyle = this.colors[i];
            }else{
                context.fillStyle = this.pieFillStyle;
            }
            context.fill();
            
            context.strokeStyle = this.pieStrokeStyle;
            context.stroke();
        }
        
        
        //Draw the outer shadow:
        
        context.save();
        
        context.shadowOffsetX = this.pieShadowOffsetX;
        context.shadowOffsetY = this.pieShadowOffsetY;
        
        context.translate(centerX, centerY);
        //context.rotate(this.pieStart* doublePI / dataSum);
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, 0);
        context.arc(0, 0, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
        
        
        context.shadowBlur = this.pieShadowBlur;
        context.shadowColor = this.pieShadowColor;
        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1.0)';
        context.fill();

        context.restore();

        //Ring-charts:
                
        if(ring){
        
            
        
            // "cut" the central part:
            
            context.save();
            
            var ringCenterRadius = radius / 1.15;
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(centerX + ringCenterRadius, centerY);
            context.arc(centerX, centerY, ringCenterRadius, 0, doublePI, false);
            
           // context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
            context.fillStyle = '#000';
            context.fill();
            
            context.restore();
            
            // draw the ring's inner shadow below the ring:
            context.save();
        
            context.shadowOffsetX = this.pieShadowOffsetX;
            context.shadowOffsetY = this.pieShadowOffsetY;
            
            context.translate(centerX, centerY);
            context.beginPath();
            // added -1 to make inner border same width as outer
            context.arc(0, 0, ringCenterRadius -1, startAngle, endAngle, false);
            
            context.shadowBlur = this.pieShadowBlur;
            context.shadowColor = this.pieShadowColor;
            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
            context.strokeStyle = this.pieStrokeStyle;
            context.stroke();

            context.restore();
                    
        }
        
        
        // draw the labels:
        
        var currentAngle = this.pieStart* doublePI / dataSum;
        var endAngle = 0;
        var incAngleBy = 0;
        
        context.beginPath();
        

        for(var i=0; i<this.data.length; i++){
            context.save();
            incAngleBy = this.data[i] * doublePI / dataSum;
            endAngle = currentAngle + incAngleBy;
            
            var mAngle = currentAngle +  incAngleBy/2;
            context.translate(centerX, centerY);
            context.rotate(mAngle);
            
            context.font = this.labelFontStyle + ' ' + this.labelFontHeight + 'px '+ this.labelFont;
            if(this.colors[i]){
                context.fillStyle = this.colors[i];
            }else{
                context.fillStyle = this.labelFillStyle;
            }
            context.textAlign = 'start';
            if(this.labels[i]){
                if( (currentAngle>Math.PI/2) && (currentAngle<=3*(Math.PI/2)) ){
                    var translateXBy = radius + this.labelMargin + context.measureText(this.labels[i]).width / 2;
                    context.translate(translateXBy, 0);
                    context.rotate(Math.PI);
                    context.translate(-translateXBy, 0);
                }
                context.textBaseline = 'middle';
                context.fillText(this.labels[i], radius+this.labelMargin, 0);
            }
            
            context.restore();
            currentAngle = endAngle;
        }
    }
    
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background: #000033;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='segmented-circle' width='200' height='200'></canvas>
```

I have tried several different things and feel like this would be a great thing to ask here.

[image: Visual of how it looks when drawing it and the end result]

The last one here is how it should look in the end.

Comment: have you solved this by now? If so, it would be nice if you could share your own solution.